# javascript user input highest of 20 numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, display

for this program, i need the user to enter 20 numbers and for the highest to be displayed. i have done a similar one with 4, which i will display below, however there must be an easier way that going through it all? any advice would be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function maxNum(num1, num2, num3, num4){
        var max = 0;
        if((num1 >= num2) && (num1 >= num3)){
            max = num1;
        }
        else if((num2 >= num1) && (num2 >= num3) && (num3 >= num4)){
            max = num2;
        }

        else if((num3 >= num1) && (num3 >= num2) && (num3 >= num4)){
            max = num3;
        }

        else{
            max = num4;
        }
    return max;
    }

    var arr = []; 
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        arr[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter a number"));
    }


    document.write(maxNum.apply(this, arr));





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im really new to js, i barely understand what a variable is. i really need idiot proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function findMaxNum(arr) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}

var arr = []; 

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  arr[i] = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'), 10);
}

var maxNum = findMaxNum(arr);
```

`Math.max` usually works with a series of numbers: `Math.max(1, 4, 10) // 10`, but here we use `apply` on the function so that it accepts an array instead.

(Note, added the radix for `parseInt`)

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b0s78e1z/1/)

Comment: i dont understand, im really new with js. could u show me the whole code please

Comment: i need to use a function and its the 'function section', any thoughts?

Comment: Added a function that returns the result of applying `Math.max` to the array.

Comment: BTW, you asked for an easier way and the easier way is without using a separate function...

Comment: ah ok, so if im to do it with 20 inputs, i need to go through it all like i did with 4?

Comment: Just change the value `4` in the loop to `20` Everything else remains the same. Test it an see - play around with the code :)

Comment: ive tried that, although the user prompt comes at 20, its only putting 4 numbers into array and displaying the highest of those 4 numbers. i hate js... its a struggle! just want to pass it and never see it again!

Comment: Not sure what you've done. [Here's the code working with 20 numbers](https://jsfiddle.net/b0s78e1z/3/)

Comment: its not displaying anything. im using notepad++

Comment: Eh? The editor doesn't matter. You're opening this JS in a browser, right? That demo will work if you open it. It goes to a site called JSFiddle and runs the code.

Comment: yeah i opened it there and copy and pasted code to notepad++ there is no display of highest number. no display of anything. thanks for helping me btw - i know im a pain, i appreciate it!

Comment: this is what i have from your code. <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'), 10);
}
var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
document.getElementById('result').textContent = maxNum;
    


    
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Before the `<script>` tag add `<body><div id="result"></div>`. That code is trying to find an element on the DOM to print the result. You could also have used `alert(maxNum` instead of `document.getElementById('result').textContent = maxNum;` to alert the result instead, for example.

Comment: Nice one. Welcome to SO, btw. Don't forget to mark the answer correct, and don't despair too much with JS. It's a fun little language but it does take some time to learn, like anything. I've been using it for years and I'm still learning. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with [`Math.max.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max). It takes an object (`null`) and an array with the values.

```js
function getMax(array) {
    var i,
        max = +array[0]; // the first element with implicit casting to number

   for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { // loop throu all elements
       if (+array[i] > max) { // with cast to number
           max = array[i];
       }
   }
   return max;
}

var userInput = ['1', 'a', '4', '-', '1000', '20'].filter(Number);
document.write(userInput + '<br>');
document.write(Math.max.apply(null, userInput) + '<br>');
document.write(getMax(userInput) + '<br>');
```

Comment: its user input, not assigned numbers. an array of the numbers is no good. can you show me how to do it with user prompt

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all values passed into your function will be numbers you can use [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) with the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) special variable.

```
function getMax()
{
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) === '[object Array]') {
        return Math.max.apply(null, arguments[0]);
    }
    return Math.max.apply(null, arguments);
}

var myArr = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20];

getMax(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10); // 10
getMax(myArr); // 20
```

The example above allows an array or a list of arguments to be passed through. This allows you to reuse where required.

Comment: sorry you've lost me 100% there!

Comment: The function allows you to get the max value from many params or from an array. There is a test on the first argument "argument[0]" to see if it is an array. If it is then it will use that argument with Math.max which is a built in JavaScript method. Follow the links. The fallback is to use the arguments variable, which is an array of all params passed into the function, directly in the Math.max call.