# Receive input numbers until the user enters a zero. Then output the highest. javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the title suggests, i have to write a program where the user enters numbers and when the number entered is 0, it outputs the highest number which was entered. i've done most of it and i know there is only a little missing but i cant figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script style="text/javascript">
    function numbers(){
    var numbers = 0;
    var outMessage = "";
    var numbersArray = new Array(numbers);

    do{
        numbers = prompt('enter 0 to cancel', 0);
    }while(isNaN(numbers));






    var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    alert(maxNum);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = maxNum;

    }
</script>
<body>
<p>Numbers Exercise</p>
<p id="numbers"></p>
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick = "numbers();">

<label id='result' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i dont know how to go any further, im not great at js. im really new to it

Comment: You create an array `numbersArray` then you add nothing to it and then you `Math.max` on an undeclared variable `arr`? Is that about it?

Comment: i dont know, can you show me please

Comment: Where's this code from?

Comment: What was wrong with the answer [the last time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359495/user-enters-amount-on-numbers-then-output-the-highest-number-javascript)?

Comment: its from a previous working program i have. i just tried to modify it.   <script style="text/javascript">
    function numbers(){
    var numbers = 0;
    var outMessage = "";
    var numbersArray = new Array(numbers);

    do{
        numbers = prompt('How many numbers?', 0);
    }while(isNaN(numbers));


    var arr = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
      arr[i] = parseInt(prompt('Enter a number'), 10);
    }

    var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    alert(maxNum);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = maxNum;
    
    }
</script>

Comment: nothing andy, its a new excersise. you would be suprised at how many i have managed to do today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your issues is that you write `var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, arr);` but you mean `var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, numbersArray);`. I think that was just forgetting to change that array name.

Then in your do while you are checking `NaN(numbers)` which will always return false if they type in valid input. You want to check `!(NaN(numbers)) so the loop quits when the number is invalid

I then check `if(numbers != 0)` inside your do while, determining if you want to push it into an array using `numbersArray.push(numbers)` and if not then break the loop.

I created a JSFiddle of this: https://jsfiddle.net/4otwrnzL/

Comment: No problem, you just made some naive errors. One helpful thing would be to hit F12 on your keyboard. This will bring up the developer console which will show you compile and runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the job, do sure if this is what you want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> <meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script style="text/javascript">
    function numbers(){
    var numbers = 0;
    var outMessage = "";
    var numbersArray = new Array(numbers);

    do{
        var number = prompt('enter 0 to cancel', 0);
        numbersArray.push(number);
    }while(isNaN(number)||number != 0);

    var maxNum = Math.max.apply(null, numbersArray);
    alert(maxNum);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = maxNum;
    }
</script>
<body>
<p>Numbers Exercise</p>
<p id="numbers"></p>
<input type="button" value="Start" onClick = "numbers();">

<label id='result' />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This almost works. If 0 is the first number it will push the 0 into the array. Which of course is not a big deal, depends on how he wants to approach the problem.